# Ruby on Rails With MongoDB 5.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I would like to know if Ruby on Rails is currently compatible with MongoDB 5.0?
Or if there is a GitHub branch that allows compatibility?

Thank you in advance

**Reference**
https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/master/reference/compatibility/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server compatibility is dictated primarily by the driver, you should use 2.15.0. The driver and Mongoid also use different definitions of "compatible", for the driver it means support of new features and for Mongoid it means the library physically works (in this sense, since MongoDB is generally forward compatible, it is likely that every Mongoid release done in the last 3 years is "compatible" with 5.0.).

Comment: Thank you, I just migrated my Rails app DB to 5.0 and it works great so far